# Empty EC2 instances list in ECS even while EC2 instance is running

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I'm creating ECS cluster for the first time.

I'm using the role with the following permissions to create the ECS cluster.

[image]

The cluster is created successfully and one instance is running but it does not show any instance in the `EC2 Instances` list

[image]

Running a task gives error

```
No Container Instances were found in your cluster.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the EC2 instance to the ECS cluster.

Take a look at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bootstrap_container_instance.html

Comment: Does not it get automatically connected when creating the Cluster? If the instance can be created then why it is not automatically attacked to ECS?

Comment: You have to bootstrap an instance to the cluster it should be assigned to. The cluster won't automatically include every ECS instance in its pool

Answer (score 0):

Instances are running but not register to the cluster having two possible reason

- Cluster name is not valid in ECS config
- ECS container role does not have the proper permission.

For the first one, do `SSH` to instant and check

```
/etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

Normally, you can find this detail in launch configuration of your cluster in `advanced configuration section`

if the name is not valid in `/etc/ecs/ecs.config` you might see this issue.

For the second, just check the logs ECS agent, you will get the helpful insight

```
 tail -f /var/log/ecs/*.log
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create EC2 from ECS-optimized AMI  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html.
You will find exact AMI ID for your region there.

By default, your EC2 launches into your default ECS cluster. To launch into a non-default cluster, choose the Advanced Details list. Then, paste the following script into the User data field, replacing your_cluster_name with the name of your cluster.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=your_cluster_name >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

More info there https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html

If both things fulfilled, in couple minutes you will see newly created EC2 on Instance tab of your ECS cluster.